# Delete element from an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need a method to delete a determinate element from a handmade list.

I have a class called AudioFile. Each element of the list is an object from this class. 
Then, I have the class FileTable, with this atributes:

```
private AudioFile[] table;
private int size;
```

I defined this method, but It doesn't work when I call it:

```
public void deleteFile(AudioFile file){
   AudioFile[] table2 = new AudioFile[100];
   int j = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       if (table[i] != file){
           table2[j] = table[i];
           j++;
        } else {
           i++;
       }
   }
    for (int k = 0; k < size); k++){
        table2[k] = table[k];
    }
    table[size-1] = null;
}
```

I think the code it's easy to understand, but if you don't understand something or you need some more information about the class AudioFile, you can say it and I'll try to help too. Thank you!

Comment: It's an array not a list anyway

Comment: I assume you know you are incrementing i twice some times.

Comment: True, but I write list because I can't do it with the .remove()

Comment: No, I don't. Sorry, I just started this year and I'm a bit lost...

Comment: You can't just `!=` to check if two objects are not same. Use `equals()` method to check for object equality, and do override the `equals()` method in `AudioFile` class. Then use `!equals()` to check if two `AudioFile`s are not same.

Comment: @Atsuko I you only want to increment i when ´table[i] != file´ condition is true you should remove i++ from for: ´for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)´ On the other hand, I don't think that is the way you want to compare your objects.

Comment: Hmmm.. so what do you recommend me? I'm really lost. I'm doing a program, but this part is getting me

Comment: I increment i when table[i]==file, if not, I increment j

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing the wheel, just use a Collection like a List or a Set. They have already a remove() method that does exactly what you want to do.
See Arrays as a low level type and always use Collection (except in really specific cases).

Comment: I can't use .remove()